Can't make Telegram WebApp Validation work using python
I am unable to validate data that Telegram sent to my WebApp..
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import typing
from urllib.parse import unquote


def parse_init_data(init_data: str) -> typing.Dict:
    return dict(param.split("=") for param in init_data.split("&"))


def parse_user_data(user_data: str) -> dict:
    return json.loads(unquote(user_data))


def _extract_hash_value(init_data: str) -> str:
    return parse_init_data(init_data)["hash"]


def generate_secret_key(telegram_bot_token: str, c_str: str = "WebAppData") -> str:
    c_str_enc = c_str.encode()
    token_enc = telegram_bot_token.encode()
    return hmac.new(token_enc, c_str_enc, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


def validate(init_data: str, secret_key: str) -> bool:
    
    hash_ = _extract_hash_value(init_data)
    unquote_init_data = unquote(init_data)
    sorted_init_data = sorted(
        [chunk.split("=") for chunk in unquote_init_data.split("&") if chunk[: len("hash=")] != "hash="],
        key=lambda x: x[0],
    )
    sorted_init_data_str = "\n".join([f"{key}={val}" for key, val in sorted_init_data])
    init_data_enc = sorted_init_data_str.encode()
    secret_key_enc = secret_key.encode()
    data_check = hmac.new(init_data_enc, secret_key_enc, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return hmac.compare_digest(hash_, data_check)
    

this code is from github. It is intended to validate data coming from Telegram to my WebApp..
I have passed all necessary things.. extracting user data from Telegram Sent data is working. But validating that data is from Telegram failing. This is initData I got
query_id=AAHkHFkqAAAAAOQcWSqv8eyu&user=%7B%22id%22%3A710483172%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Ro%27zmat%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Otajonov%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22OtajonovR%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22is_premium%22%3Atrue%2C%22allows_write_to_pm%22%3Atrue%7D&auth_date=1713215281&hash=c7907965154661f6f322d02e4a97086568e033980818396b623649ba3a062685

and this code is my django view that trying to validate using above functions:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .webapp_auth import parse_init_data, parse_user_data, validate, generate_secret_key
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

def business_settings_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        init_data_string = request.POST.get('initData')
        secret_key = generate_secret_key("6194107681:AAFc76vwjlxsWA...")
        
        db_user = None
        tg_user = None
        init_data = None
        is_valid = False
        
        if validate(init_data_string, secret_key):
            
            is_valid = True


            
            
            
        init_data = parse_init_data(init_data_string)
        tg_user = parse_user_data(init_data['user'])
        
        try:
            db_user = User.objects.get(telegram_id=tg_user['id'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            db_user = None
        
        
        context = {'db_user': db_user, 'init_data': init_data, 'is_valid': is_valid}
        return render(request, 'business-settings.html', context)


    else:
        return render(request, 'webapp-init.html')


I tried to use everything except validate(). all working fine. But validate() is returning False all the time

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
